# Updating the color of rows of a TableView consumes too much CPU

Tags: javafx-8

I am making an application that receives alerts.

An alert can have 4 possible states:

- Unresolved_New_0
- Unresolved_New_1
- Unresolved_Old
- Resolved

When an alert is received, it is in Unresolved_New_0 state. For 10 seconds, every 0.5s the state changes from Unresolved_New_0 to Unresolved_New_1 and vice-versa. Depending on state I, set a different background color to the table row (so that it flashes, for 10s).
When the 10s pass, the alert transitions to Unresolved_Old state. This causes its color to stop changing.

To implement this, I have a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor that I use to submit an implementation of Runnable that for some time executes a runnable using Platform.runLater.

```
static class FxTask extends Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     * @param runnableDuring Runnable to be run while the task is active (run on the JavaFX application thread).
     * @param runnableAfter Runnable to be run after the given duration is elapsed (run on the JavaFX application thread).
     * @param duration Duration to run this task for.
     * @param unit Time unit.
     */
    public static FxTask create(final Runnable runnableDuring, final Runnable runnableAfter, final long duration, final TimeUnit unit) {

        return new FxTask(runnableDuring, runnableAfter, duration, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (System.nanoTime() - mTimeStarted >= mTimeUnit.toNanos(mDuration) )
        {
            cancel();
            Platform.runLater(mRunnableAfter);
        }
        else
            Platform.runLater(mRunnableDuring);
    }

    private FxTask(final Runnable during, final Runnable after, final long duration, final TimeUnit unit) {

        mRunnableDuring = during;
        mRunnableAfter = after;

        mDuration = duration;
        mTimeUnit = unit;

        mTimeStarted = System.nanoTime();
    }

    private final Runnable mRunnableDuring;
    private final Runnable mRunnableAfter;
    private final long mDuration;
    private final TimeUnit mTimeUnit;

    private final long mTimeStarted;
}
```

And I schedule Alerts using that Runnable as follows:

```
final Alert alert = new Alert(...);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(FxTask.create(
    () -> {
        switch (alert.alertStateProperty().get()) {

            case UNRESOLVED_NEW_0:
                alert.alertStateProperty().set(Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_1);
                refreshTable(mAlertsTable);
                break;

            case UNRESOLVED_NEW_1:
                alert.alertStateProperty().set(Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_0);
                refreshTable(mAlertsTable);
                break;
        }
    },
    () -> { // This is run at the end
        if (equalsAny(alert.alertStateProperty().get(), Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_0, SpreadAlert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_1)) {
            alert.alertStateProperty().set(Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_OLD);
            refreshTable(mAlertsTable);
        }
    },
    10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
);
```

Note: alertStateProperty() is not shown on the TableView (it is not bound to any of its columns).
So in order to force JavaFx to redraw, I have to use refreshTable(), which unfortunately redraws the whole table (?).

```
public static <T> void refreshTable(final TableView<T> table) {

        table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
        table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem is that even if I create a small number of Alerts at the same time, CPU usage goes very high: from 20% to 84% sometimes, averaging at about 40%. When the 10s pass for all alerts, CPU consumptions returns to 0%. If I comment out refreshTable(), CPU stays near 0%, which indicates that it is the problem.

Why is so much CPU being used? (I have 8 cores by the way).
Is there another way to redraw just a single row without redrawing the whole table?

I even tried a 'hacky' method -- changing all values of the Alerts and then resetting them back to cause JavaFx to detect the change and redraw, but CPU was again at the same levels.

Comment: Is `Alert` the item type for your `TableView`? How are you currently actually changing the color of the row when the property changes (I can see you redraw all of the first column - which you shouldn't need to do -, but when you show the column how is it's color determined?).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient way to change the color of a table row is to use a table row factory, have the table row it creates observe the appropriate property, and update one or more [CSS `PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) states as appropriate. Then just define the colors in an external css file.

Here's a standalone version of the application you described. I just used a `Timeline` to perform the "flashing new alerts", which is less code; but use the executor as you have it if you prefer. The key idea here is the table row factory, and the pseudoclass state it manipulates by observing the property. On my system, if I fill the entire table with new (flashing) rows, the CPU doesn't exceed about 35% (percentage of one core), which seems perfectly acceptable.

Note that `PseudoClass` was introduced in Java 8. In earlier versions of JavaFX you can achieve the same by manipulating the style classes instead, though you have to be careful not to duplicate any style classes as they are stored as a `List`. Anecdotally, the pseudoclass approach is more efficient.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class AlertTableDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Alert> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Name", Alert::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Value", Alert::valueProperty));
        TableColumn<Alert, Alert> resolveCol = 
                createColumn("Resolve", ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Alert>::new);
        resolveCol.setCellFactory(this::createResolveCell);
        table.getColumns().add(resolveCol);

        // just need a wrapper really, don't need the atomicity...
        AtomicInteger alertCount = new AtomicInteger(); 
        Random rng = new Random();

        Button newAlertButton = new Button("New Alert");
        newAlertButton.setOnAction( event -> 
            table.getItems().add(new Alert("Alert "+alertCount.incrementAndGet(), 
                    rng.nextInt(20)+1)));

        // set psuedo-classes on table rows depending on alert state:
        table.setRowFactory(tView -> {

            TableRow<Alert> row = new TableRow<>();

            ChangeListener<Alert.State> listener = (obs, oldState, newState) -> 
                updateTableRowPseudoClassState(row, row.getItem().getState());

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldAlert, newAlert) -> {
                if (oldAlert != null) {
                    oldAlert.stateProperty().removeListener(listener);
                }
                if (newAlert == null) {
                    clearTableRowPseudoClassState(row);
                } else {
                    updateTableRowPseudoClassState(row, row.getItem().getState());
                    newAlert.stateProperty().addListener(listener);
                }
            });

            return row ;
        });

        // flash new alerts:
        table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Alert> change) -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    List<? extends Alert> newAlerts = 
                            new ArrayList<>(change.getAddedSubList());
                    flashAlerts(newAlerts);
                }
            }
        });


        HBox controls = new HBox(5, newAlertButton);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, controls, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("alert-table.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void flashAlerts(List<? extends Alert> newAlerts) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), 
                event -> {
                    for (Alert newAlert : newAlerts) {
                        if (newAlert.getState()==Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_0) {
                            newAlert.setState(Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_1);
                        } else if (newAlert.getState() == Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_1){
                            newAlert.setState(Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_0);
                        }
                    }
                }));
        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> {
            for (Alert newAlert : newAlerts) {
                if (newAlert.getState() != Alert.State.RESOLVED) {
                    newAlert.setState(Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_OLD);
                }
            }
        });
        timeline.setCycleCount(20);
        timeline.play();
    }

    private void clearTableRowPseudoClassState(Node node) {
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unresolved-new"), false);
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unresolved-new-alt"), false);
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unresolved-old"), false);
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("resolved"), false);
    }

    private void updateTableRowPseudoClassState(Node node, Alert.State state) {
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unresolved-new"), 
                state==Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_0);
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unresolved-new-alt"), 
                state==Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_1);
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unresolved-old"), 
                state==Alert.State.UNRESOLVED_OLD);
        node.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("resolved"), 
                state==Alert.State.RESOLVED);       
    }

    private TableCell<Alert, Alert> createResolveCell(TableColumn<Alert, Alert> col) {
        TableCell<Alert, Alert> cell = new TableCell<>();
        Button resolveButton = new Button("Resolve");

        resolveButton.setOnAction(event -> 
            cell.getItem().setState(Alert.State.RESOLVED));

        cell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        cell.graphicProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty())
                .then((Node)null)
                .otherwise(resolveButton));
        return cell ;
    }

    private <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createColumn(String title, 
            Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> propertyMapper) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> propertyMapper.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Alert {
        public enum State { 
            UNRESOLVED_NEW_0, UNRESOLVED_NEW_1, UNRESOLVED_OLD, RESOLVED 
        }

        private final ObjectProperty<State> state = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        public final ObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() {
            return this.state;
        }
        public final AlertTableDemo.Alert.State getState() {
            return this.stateProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setState(final AlertTableDemo.Alert.State state) {
            this.stateProperty().set(state);
        }
        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }
        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }
        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }
        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public Alert(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
            setState(State.UNRESOLVED_NEW_0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

alert-table.css:

```
.table-row-cell:resolved {
    -fx-background: green ;
}
.table-row-cell:unresolved-old {
    -fx-background: red ;
}
.table-row-cell:unresolved-new {
    -fx-background: blue ;
}
.table-row-cell:unresolved-new-alt {
    -fx-background: yellow ;
}
```